# SliverAppBar Title Issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to hide title when appbar opens, but when I scroll that time I want appbar title. I attached video you can check it. Currently, happen is there I can not hide title while I use sliver appbar.

```
NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 250.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  title: const Text("Top cricket Stories",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: AppConstants.clrBlack,
                        fontSize: AppConstants.mediumFontSize16,
                      )),
                  background: Image.asset(
                    widget.image!,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 15),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                widget.title!,
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: AppConstants.mediumFontSize17,
                    color: AppConstants.clrBlack,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                widget.date!,
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: AppConstants.mediumFontSize13,
                    color: AppConstants.clrGreyText),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                widget.subtitle!,
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: AppConstants.mediumFontSize15,
                    color: AppConstants.clrBlack),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

[This is a video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14BdIU94ux05qWo9LAUUD3cHSovjffRCT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Code Added   @HarshSureja

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-add-sliverappbar-to-your-flutter-app/)!

Just check this website and you will get your answer .
The only things that has to checked are floating , snap , pinned.

OR

What I have seen in your video, you can set this:-

pinned: false,  snap: true,  floating: true:

Comment: Not that way, I want When Image displays that time "GOA" text will be not visible, but when I scroll and Image transfer to appbar that time it will be display